# populate dropbox based on cell info and then populate other cells based on info selected

Tags: excel, validation, dropbox, offset, vba

I have 633 rows of vehicles names with id numbers and specifications. In the row of vehicle 1, I want to use a drop down to select chassis types and populate some of the rows with this data. In chassis worksheet, I have a list of chassis with the vehicle numbers they can be used on. eg. chassis 4567 can be used on vehicle 1, 37, 18. and Vehicle 1 can use chassis 4567, 4657, and 8865. Also gearboxes ect. The main vehicle specs sheet then has multiple drop downs that if selected will change specifications for the vehicle in that row.
How do I do this. for 688 vehicles?
any help will do as I have been trying to look for examples. I would like to do it using vba for excel.

The main sheet:[The main sheet where the dropboxes will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9MTI.png)

The suspension sheet:[The suspension sheet that will populate the suspension drop box based on the vehicles id in the row and when changed will populate the cells with data on that suspension.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0qP3.png)

The general vehicle details[The general vehicle details and vehicle id used to populate all fields in the main sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2uur.png)

These sheets are all connected to a Web Api and update weekly. That part is all working. Just the drop boxes ...

Tried the following few bits of code: **(Updated code)**

```
Private Sub Sheet_Initialize()

Dim sn, e
Dim rngTurTank As Range
Dim oDictionary As Object
Dim x As Integer

Set oDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set rngTurTank = Sheets("Turrets").Range("b2" &   Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    With Sheets("Total details").cbTurret
        For Each cel In rngTurTank
            If Doictionary.exists(cel.Value) Then
            'Do Nothing
            Else
                oDictionary.Add cel.Value, 0
                .AddItem cel.Value
            End If
        Next cel
    End With

    Dim iTurTank As Long

        lbTurTank.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        iTurTank = Sheets("Turrets").Range("B2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Count
        Set rngTurTank = Sheets("Turrets").Range("B2" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value
        If iTurTank > 0 And rngTurTank = Range("A3").Value Then
            lbTurTank.RowSource = Sheets("Turrets").Range("D2:D")
        Else
            lbTurTank.RowSource = ""
            lbTurTank.AddItem "Empty"
        End If
```

These didnt work so I tried this:

```
'the reference string to the source range
Dim strTurretRange As String

'Turrets
strTurretRange = Sheets("Turrets").Range("D2",    Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Select
    With Sheet5.Range("M3").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=strTurretRange
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

How do I populate the list only when the tank id is the same. ie. colomn A

Try number 2

```
With Sheet5.Range("M3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=VLOOKUP(A3;allTurrets;3;0)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

and I have tried number 3:

```
With Sheet5.Range("M3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDEX(sTurrets;MATCH(A3;sTank_id_turret;0))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

This last one works but only gives me 1 return value where I need 4 to 5 values in the drop box to select from?

Try number 4:

Used the following: =OFFSET(sTurrets;MATCH($A$3; sTank_id_turret;0);0;COUNTIF(sTank_id_turret;$A$3);1) 
Gets the right amount of matches, but not the first correct one. ie if the turrets names for tank_id 14913 were 't34 mod, Cruizer Mk1, Cz03 LTvz35, Leophard Prototype A1 and Leophard Prototype A2. This formula omits t34 mod and then added in Porsche T169, which is for tank_14914.

1. What am I missing to load a complete list in order?
2. Is there a way to load the last value in the list by default?
3. How do I populate the cells to the right of the DV?
   Any help with this will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, Art, go ahead and do it in VBA. Once you have done some work and run into problems, you can come back. We are not a coding service.

Comment: Can you post a snapshot of your data .. and how would you like your output?

Comment: Thank you for even coming to the post. I appreciate it. Paul Ogilvie, could you possibly direct me where I can start. Website ect. i have been looking.

Comment: Yasser, On the main sheet I want to be able to load the tank_id into "A1" and then based on this number, populate the colored cells as drop downs/validation.  These are filled with the names of the suspensions that a curtain tank can use. (based on suspensions,Tank, cell "B" and the value in main sheet, "A1") After a suspension (Dropdown in "X3")  is selected then the cells to the right are updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked a bit more on this and I made a table out of the data. I have the following code:

```
Application.Goto Reference:="sTank_id_turret"

With Sheet5.Range("M3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=VLOOKUP(A3;tblTurrets;3;0)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

I am doing it this way as I have 5 different validations on this sheet from 5 different sheets all on 1 row. There are 650 rows of info.

It just gives me 1 value in the drop down. I have to have 4 to 5 to choose from. Why
Why do I just have 1

Comment: Ok got it ... just use the reference "sTank_id_turret" as the formula :) Like so: Formula1:="=sTank_id_turret"

Comment: if this is NOT an answer it should be an [edit] to your question so we know where you are currently at.

Comment: See this for dependent drop down lists: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-steps-to-adding-a-dependent-list-control-to-an-excel-sheet/

Comment: Thanks QHarr. Will remember that. thanks for the help. will go look

Comment: Doesn't really help me. I have used   =VLOOKUP(A3;allTurrets;3;0) and it did not work then I tried =INDEX(sTurrets;MATCH(A3;sTank_id_turret;0)). That works but only gives me 1 return value where I need 4 to 5 values in the drop box to select from. I have been looking at:=IFERROR(INDEX(sTurrets; SMALL(IF(A$3= sTank_id_turret; ROW(sTurrets)-2;""); ROW()-2));""). But still don't quite know how to get multiple answers in the Data Validation. Keeps giving me a "List source must be a delimited list ...." Help